# How do I remove this rectangular of image button

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

There is a default rectangular background in my Image Button. I want to remove this [image]

This is related codes:

```
<ImageButton
     android:layout_width="62dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:id="@+id/im16"
     android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
     android:src="@drawable/off1"/>
```

Comment: are they two different images ?

Comment: Did you try using `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`?

Comment: use wrap_content for width and height and try

Comment: You can use ImageView as a button.

Comment: Well I guess the original image is like that.You should use a .png image instead.

Comment: Hey Apoorv thanks man. I think it's worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this

```
<ImageButton
   android:layout_width="62dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_height="60dp"
   android:id="@+id/im16"
   android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
   android:background="@drawable/off1"/>
```

just change your android:src to android:background

Comment: @MohammadFarahi ok remove weight and see

Answer (score 0):

You will want to set the background of the imageButton to be something invisible. I do this by making the following XML drawable and setting it to the ImageButton's background. This will let the button still show a color when it is clicked, but blank otherwise.

blank_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/some_color" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="62dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/im16"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/off1"
    android:background="@drawable/blank_selector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

best solution is

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: Mark the appropriate answer correct so that others may go in the right way.